# How to set compatible iOS

Tags: iphone

**We found that your app crashed on iPhone 4 running iOS 6, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.**
Application is crashing on launch.
What is the solution to solve this issue...?
Can I set the iOS compatibility at the time of deploying app on iTunesConnect.

Comment: No, you should always support the most recent iOS version. Your app will be rejected until this is fixed.

Comment: I believe iOS 6 is still in its beta phase.. The official release date being 19th sept 2012. So I suggest you to run it in iOS 5 for now untill the issue is fixed. and will be done only till 19th of this month..

Comment: In my device with iOS 5.1.1, applicaiton is properly deploying & testing also then also apple store gives crash issue tha "in iPhone 4 with iOS 5.1.1 application is crashing"

Comment: What is base sdk version set in your app plist file??

Comment: @iCreative...Below is the current .plist....is there any changes required...?

Answer (score 0):

This is .plist file setting of my application

[image]